Cannot convert column into bool with simple filter condition with any operator
I am trying to form filter condition dynamically from dict structure in python and it is very simple condition which is giving below error:
Final constructed filter condition: Column<'(CompanyCode IN (1930, 1931))'> Type of final_condition: <class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'> PySparkValueError: [CANNOT_CONVERT_COLUMN_INTO_BOOL] Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

I have data and column as below:
data = [("John", 1930), ("Doe", 1931), ("Jane", 1940)]
columns = ["Name", "Code"]

I am trying to mimic below filter using dynamic code:
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=columns)
df.filter(F.col("Code").isin(1930, 1931)).show()

my code is as below:
    {
        "conditions": [
            {"column": "Code", "operator": "IN", "values": [1930, 1931]}
        ]
    }

and below is my code:
def construct_filter_condition(conditions):

    """
    Construct filter condition from a list of conditions.
    :param conditions: List of conditions
    :return: PySpark Column expression
    """
    combined_conditions = []
    for condition in conditions:
        

        column = condition["column"]
        operator = condition["operator"].lower()
        values = condition.get("values")
        value = condition.get("value")

        if operator == "in":
            new_condition = F.col(column).isin(values)
        elif operator == "eq":
            new_condition = F.col(column) == value
        elif operator == "ne":
            new_condition = F.col(column) != value
        elif operator == "lt":
            new_condition = F.col(column) < value
        elif operator == "le":
            new_condition = F.col(column) <= value
        elif operator == "gt":
            new_condition = F.col(column) > value
        elif operator == "ge":
            new_condition = F.col(column) >= value
        elif operator == "not_in":
            new_condition = ~F.col(column).isin(values)
        else:
            continue  # Skip invalid operators
    
        combined_conditions.append(new_condition)
    
    # Combine all conditions using 'AND' logic
        if combined_conditions:
            final_condition = combined_conditions[0]
            for cond in combined_conditions[1:]:
                final_condition = final_condition & cond
            return final_condition
        else:
            return None

Example condition:
    flt_conditions = [
        {
            "conditions": [
                {"column": "CompanyCode", "operator": "IN", "values": [1930, 1931]}
            ]
        }
    ]

Construct and apply filter
final_condition = construct_filter_condition(flt_conditions[0]["conditions"])
if final_condition:
    print(f"Constructed filter condition: {final_condition}")
    filtered_df = df.filter(final_condition)
    print(f"DataFrame filter syntax: df.filter({final_condition})")
    filtered_df.show()
else:
    print("No valid filter conditions provided.")


i am getting below output from the code and error

Final constructed filter condition: Column<'(CompanyCode IN (1930, 1931))'>
Type of final_condition: <class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>
PySparkValueError: [CANNOT_CONVERT_COLUMN_INTO_BOOL] Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

This is actually just an issue with if final_condition: because final_condition is a column filter and can't be interpreted as a boolean. Instead, I would try using if final_condition is not None: because your function construct_filter_condition returns either a column filter or None.
if final_condition is not None:
    print(f"Constructed filter condition: {final_condition}")
    filtered_df = df.filter(final_condition)
    print(f"DataFrame filter syntax: df.filter({final_condition})")
    filtered_df.show()
else:
    print("No valid filter conditions provided.")

Output:
Constructed filter condition: Column<'(Code IN (1930, 1931))'>
DataFrame filter syntax: df.filter(Column<'(Code IN (1930, 1931))'>)
+----+----+
|Name|Code|
+----+----+
|John|1930|
| Doe|1931|
+----+----+

